# NIntegrate & non-numerical values

Tags: numerical-integration

I am wondering why I am receiving the message "The integrand ... has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region ..." for a particular calculation I am running. How can I change my code so that this is not an issue? A simple example is copied below.

```
a = 1/20; b = 1/5;
FF[y_] := Exp[I a y - 1/2 b^2 y^2];
f[x_] := NIntegrate[E^(-I x y) FF[y], {y, 0.0, 100}];
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -100, 100}]
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = 1/20; b = 1/5;
FF[y_?NumericQ] := Exp[I a y - 1/2 b^2 y^2];
f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[E^(-I x y) FF[y], {y, 0.0, 100}];
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -100, 100}]
```

converges slowly ... to Pi

Comment: That did the trick. I just noticed that `FF[y_Real]` and `f[x_Real]` also solves the issue. Shame it slows the code down though...

Comment: Would you know where I can find some general information on when such conditions on function parameters should be used?

Comment: @Freakalien Take a look at the first two questions here http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes