# Numerical nonlinear constrained optimisation - minimizing maximum of multi-variable function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear

Recenty I've been working on numerical nonlinear constrained optimisation problem. My goal is to minimize maximum of multi-variable function. This problem varies from the "minimax/maximin" problem presented in the Mathematica documentation. Definition of my problem:

```
minimize (over {xi}) maximum {over t} f(t,{xi}), where 0≤t≤1 and 0≤{xi}≤1 ∀ i∈N
```

Simple example:

```
minimize (over {x1,x2}) maximum (over t) of a function f(t,x1,x2)=sin(x1^3-t^2+x2), where 0≤t≤1, 0≤x1≤1, 0≤x2≤1
```

My Mathematica code:

```
f[t_,x1_,x2_]:=Sin[x1^3-t^2+x2]
max=NMaximize[{f[t,x1,x2],0≤t≤1},{t}]
NMinimize[{max[[1]],0≤x1≤1,0≤x2≤1},{x1,x2}]
```

Second line will obviously output an error since Mathematica wont be able to perform NMaximize for a specified function sice x1 and x2 are unknown. Is there any way to force mathematica to first perform NMinimize, take some arbitrary values of x1 and x2 and then perfrom NMaximize to make this idea work? Are there any other solutions to this problem?

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34657/nintegrate-non-numerical-values) and related questions

Comment: I You are right. Changing the definition to max[x1_?NumericQ] := First@NMaximize[{f[t, x1], -1 <= t <= 1}, {t}] and NMinimize[{max[x1], -1 <= x1 <= 1}, x1] yields the right result {2.9933*10^-9, {x1 -> -2.9933*10^-9}} , but takes very long time. Needs further examination, why.

Comment: I deleted my anwer to find a better one.

Comment: One way is to use `FunctionInterpolation`.  `max[x1_] := First@NMaximize[{f[t, x1], -1 <= t <= 1}, {t}] ` and   `g = FunctionInterpolation[max[x1], {x1, -1, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12]`  Ignore error messages. `NMinimize[{g[x1], -1 <= x1 <= 1}, x1] ` yields  `{8.94213*10^-10, {x1 -> -2.54145*10^-9}} ` very fast.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and knowledge. I've been testing your idea for past hour and it works wonders unless form of the function is not "too complicated". I guess it cannot interpolate some NMaximize functions  when number of variables is excessive. My goal is to increase the number of variables to possible maximum starting from five f[t,x1...x4]. For my function I was able to solve it for only 3 variables, assuming the values of the rest two. I would like to share my "real" function, however it has complex form and Im pretty sure it wouldnt fit in a comment.